# error running viso2_ros in monocular mode

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,
I'm trying to use viso2_ros for monocular visual odometry.
I'm using gscam package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/gscam) to create a video stream:

```
roscd gscam
export GSCAM_CONFIG="multifilesrc location=\"2010_03_09_drive_0019/I1_%06d.png\" index=0 num-buffers=-1  caps=\"image/png,framerate=\(fraction\)1/1\" ! videorate framerate=5/1 ! pngdec ! ffmpegcolorspace"
rosrun gscam gscam
```

Note: All *.png images are downloaded from http://www.cvlibs.net/datasets/karlsruhe_sequences.html

After I run viso2_ros to get odometry:

```
roscd viso2_ros
rosrun viso2_ros mono_odometer _camera_height:=0.555 _camera_pitch:=-0.523598776 _ransac_iters:=2000 _inlier_threshold:=0.00001 _motion_threshold:=100.0 /image:=gscam/image_raw
```

But after some image, I get the following error:
ERROR: Cannot get submatrix [3..3] x [0..-1] of a (0x0) matrix.

This is due by a submatrix operation form a small matrix to a bigger one..
Can anyone help me please?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42982/error-running-viso2_ros-in-monocular-mode/) by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 252 on 2012-09-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) on 2012-09-04**:
Which sequence are you using? How does your camera info look like? I cannot reproduce the error using the sequence 2010_03_09_drive_0023.zip.

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-09-11**:
@Stephan Hi Stephen, I'm using  2010_03_09_drive_0023.zip , but I didn't set any CameraInfo, how can I set it? there is a file called "2010_03_09_calib.txt" that contains all camera calibration info. I need to find a way to pass them to mono_odometer application.

**Comment by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) on 2012-09-11**:
@Stephan I set the right camera info modifying "camera_parameters.txt" (the file loaded by default during gscam startup). So, now I'm passing the right "sensor_msgs/CameraInfo" to viso2_ros ( https://plus.google.com/photos/110821693483007740796/albums/5786873215167754961?a), but the problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the error setting the right camera calibration parameters, for details see this other topic:
http://answers.ros.org/question/41936/error-with-viso2_ros-package-cannot-get-submatrix-33-x-0-1-of-a-0x0-matrix/
Regards

---

Originally posted by [aldo85ita](https://answers.ros.org/users/3035/aldo85ita/) with karma: 252 on 2012-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1